# Get a table with contacts who liked one comment

Tags: facebook-like

Sorry if this is not a programming question, but I didn't find a place to ask it. I need to copy a table with all the contacts that have given me a like on one of my comments. How can I get this and update it daily? Do this require programming?

Comment: Well actually it might be programmatic. Buuut... can I please know why you need the info :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course this will require programming, please also don't use tags that are not related. I'm not familiarized with Facebook API (don't even know if it's possible) but you would first need to submit an app, request that data from the API (usually on JSON), pass thru PHP and echo it on a table, I don't think this is possible due to obvious safety stuff. And to update it daily, you would need to set a CRON job and post it on a database, maybe using MySQL.

Good luck ;)